# laravel-> on select change, submit to Controller show

Tags: php, rest, laravel, laravel-blade

I must be missing something. I'm trying to get the on submit from a select, to show fields on the selected item.

```
//the view
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'user.show', 'name' => "frm_select_client")) }}

        {{Form::select('client_id', array('-1' => 'Please select...') + $usersperclient, null, array('class' => 'selectpicker', 'id' => 'client_id', 'name' => 'client_id', "onchange" => "document.frm_select_client.submit();") );}}

{{ Form::close() }}

//routes.php
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

I looking for a way to put the URL user/id (user/1901) to then go to UserController::show().
All the examples i've been seeing go directly from a link to the show:

```
<a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="{{ URL::to('user/' . $value->id) }}">Show this user</a>
```

I know i could do this in javascript, but i'm looking to do it in the best way, since i'll be doing this probably a lot. Hope this is clear.
Thx in advance!

EDIT:
I was looking for a way to format the form submit to accomplish the resourceful format, in this case (user/{id} for the show).

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: ok.. sorry about that... the clearest way i can think of to reformulate this: how to arrange the view to when i change the select (onchange), it submits to user.show route, or in route language: user/(the_id_selected_in_select)

Comment: Check the answer, let me know if you want this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to use `JavaScript` to fire the select's `change` event and you may try this:

```
var select = document.getElementById('client_id');
select.addEventListener('change', function(){
    this.form.submit();
}, false);
```

This will `submit` the `form` on `change` event and you may also try this as well:

```
var select = document.getElementById('client_id');
select.onchange = function(){
    this.form.submit();
};
```

Using `jQuery`, you may try this:

```
$('#client_id').on('change', function(e){
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Or using inline event handling, you may try this (Add this in the attribute's array):

```
"onchange" => "this.form.submit()"
```

Above code will produce something like this:

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

To generate the `url` you may use this:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'user/' . $user->id, 'name' => "frm_select_client")) }}
```

Also, you may use `route` like this (assumed `user.show` is the route name for url `user/{id}`):

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => array('user.show', $user->id), 'name' => "frm_select_client")) }}
```

Make sure you pass the `$user` object to your `view` when loading the form, using something like this (Basically from a `Controller`):

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $user = User::find($id);
    return View::make('userform')->with('user', $user);
}
```

### Update:

Since the `user id` is being selected dynamically from the `select` so you have to use `JavaScript` to set the form `action` with `id` and in this case, you may try following approach:

```
// Add this line before you submit the form
this.form.action = 'user/' + this.value;
// Now submit
this.form.submit();
```

Or using `jQuery` you may try this:

```
$('#client_id').on('change', function(e){
    var select = $(this), form = select.closest('form');
    form.attr('action', 'user/' + select.val());
    form.submit();
});
```

In this case, keep the form `action` blank, use a blank string like `url => ''`.

Comment: yea.. and then how can i pass to the controller the user i want to show? Since the routes are waiting for the format -user/id- to show. I could simply use a link instead of a form... this is what i'm exploring here... the best way to do it... thx for u r answer!

Comment: thx again! the thing is that i dont know the $user->id until its selected from the select. This selected item would be the one i'll pass to the usercontroller::show(). So, i think that using a form wasn't a good idea of mine.

Comment: thx a lot for u r answer! this should work and its not long. I'm wondering if there is not a -no-javascript way...

Comment: No, this requires `JS`

Comment: You may do it without `JavaScript` if you provide a `submit` button to be clicked by the user after (s)he select the user id, in this case user has to manually submit the form and also your server side implementation needs to be changed because you have to create a static `url` like `example.com/user/show` and you can access the selected user `id` using `$userID = Input::get('client_id')`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty easy answer that does not require the form to be submitted.

### Route to show the page

```
Route::get('select', function()
{
    return View::make('select')->with('opts', User::lists('username', 'id'));
});
```

The `lists()` function is amazing for setting up options in a select dropdown.  It's just creating a key-value array for us right from the database.

### Setting up the form

```
{{ Form::open() }}
    {{ Form::select('user', $opts, null, array('id' => 'userid')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}

<span id='username'></span>
<span id='email'></span>
```

Just pass the array we made with the `lists()` function as the second argument when setting up our dropdown.  Also made places to set the username and email just for an example.  The third argument would be the default if you wanted to set one, and the 4th is setting the properties of the element.  You really just need an id for this example so jQuery can easily grab onto it.

### Event handler using jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#userid').on('change', function() {
            var data = {
                'id': $(this).val()
            };
            console.log(data);
            $.post('{{ route("ajax.user_select") }}', data, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                /*optional stuff to do after success */
                console.log(data);
                $('#username').html(data.username);
                $('#email').html(data.email);
            });
        });
    });
```

Using the `route()` function provided by Laravel makes it very easy to call whatever route you want from javascript.  The only downside is you must place this in a blade template file.  I usually create a `scripts` section on my master template just for this.  We will set that route up next.

We are using Javascript to set the username and email pages on our view to the value of the selected user.

### Route being called by the Javascript event handler

```
Route::post('select', array('as' => 'ajax.user_select', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getUser'));
```

Very easy here, it's just saying it is expecting a post and it tells it where to route the post.  The name here matches the argument we sent to the `route()` function in the previous step.

### Our function to get the user as was defined in the last step

```
public function getUser()
{
    return Response::json(User::find(Input::get('id')));
}
```

Nothing difficult here.  Just getting the user we wanted and returning it as a json response.

### Note:

This method would allow people to see other user's hashed password.  Even hashed, you probably don't want to show that information.  To hide a piece of information when doing these things, you can add `public $hidden = array('password');` to your `User` model.  You could also add other column names from your database as well if you wish for those to remain  hidden.